# MS SQL driver issue with Struts 2 tomcat 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, tomcat7

I am developing web application using Tomcat 7 and connecting to a MSSQL 2008 DB.

While executing a DB operation from any Java console based application, it succeeds. Same code fails to execute while performing same operations from web application with the message "No suitable drivers found". We are using [sqljdbc4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11774)

URL `private String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.100.41.232;databaseName=iptvdb;";`

Not able to understand the this strange behaviour. Any workarounds?

Also tried with : port 1433 but it's still not working.

Comment: Issue should not be struts2 related, it is between JDBC/and the driver. Are you using the same driver in the java console applications? I use Squirrel SQL client for this purpose.

Comment: @Quaternion yes its nt abt Struts 2 .. its jst there to mention the basic components. And yes, I am using same driver for console application.

Comment: I would follow the instructions for setting up a connection pool with your application server instead. I wish I could be more helpful (glassfish user) but since no one else is commenting that is where I would start.

Comment: Where have you placed your JDBC driver when running on Tomcat?

Comment: tried by placing under web-inf/lib earlier and then in apache home folder's lib.. same result!!!

Answer (score 0):

That error means it cant find the JDBC driver on your classpath. Do you have the JDBC driver? You need to have the MySQL JDBC drivers. If you dont have it, it can be downloaded from the MySQL website.

If you do have the driver or have downloaded it, make sure it is in the correct place. It needs to be placed on your classpath. This usually means one of two places

- With your Struts application under the WEB-INF/lib folder
- With the application server. For tomcat this is usually in $CATALINA_HOME/lib

Comment: tried by placing at both the places. Still not working. Thats where I am confused